# How do I convert stove top pressure cooker recipes into electric pressure cooker recipes?

Tags: pressure-cooker

Many of the pressure cooker recipes I see online seem to be using a stove top cooker, and some say cook on low heat or high heat, or start on high heat and then reduce to low heat while maintaining pressure, etc.  I have an electric pressure cooker, and it allows you to choose low or high pressure and a pressurized cook time, but does not allow for adjusting the heat.  How can I use these stovetop recipes with my electric pressure cooker?

Comment: I edited original asker's question to remove recipe request - that way we can explain to them how to use the stovetop recipes they already found.

Comment: It seems like there are several good questions that could come out of this: How to change existing recipes. Resources or search terms for finding good recipes. What factors make a recipe well suited for the cooker. etc.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference I know between stovetop and electric pressure cookers is that the electric ones take much longer to release pressure after cooking. The ones I've seen/compared take roughly twice as long (10-15 minutes for stovetop, 20-25 for electric). Biggest reason I can think of is that you can move the normal pressure cooker away from the hot stove, but you can't move the electric one away from its heating element.

As a result, I would adjust the cooking times down by 10 minutes or so to compensate.

In regards to the high/low heat, the main advantage of electric pressure cookers is that they are more energy efficient, and are designed to distribute heat well. You shouldn't need to worry about heat variance--get it up to the pressure you need and start the timer.